# Ubuntu screen keeps pixelating

Tags: display, screen

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on an HP laptop. After a few minutes the screen blurs and pixelates until I switch the screen resolution. This works for a few minutes and then blurs again. Each time I change the resolution -no matter what setting- it works but only for a few minutes.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed computer equipment information?